# How do I move my pictures from my Picture Library to my SkyDrive

Tags: windows-8, windows-rt

I have a Surface RT. I have some nice photos in my Pictures Library. I would like to move those to my SkyDrive. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to bulk upload a number of pictures from your Pictures Library do the following:

1. Open the Pictures app, and navigate to the folder/album containing the images you want to upload.
2. Select the images you want to upload:

   1. For a few images, select them individually by swiping down on each image (or right click if you've got the keyboard out).
   2. For all images, or most of them, swipe down from top of the screen (or right click on the screen) to bring up the actions tab, and press "Select all", you can then deselect a few using the same method as to select:

[image: Multiple images selected]

To save to SkyDrive:

3. Swipe in from the right to open the charms bar, and press "Share".
4. Select "SkyDrive" and then choose the folder you want to upload them to:

[image: Share to SkyDrive]

There doesn't appear to be a way to create a new folder in SkyDrive during the "Share" process, so you need to use an existing folder.